# Add pagination to custom page

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I have added my own custom post type `continent` using [register_post_type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) and have created the template single-continent.php. The page is accessed via /moving-to/continent-name.

```
register_post_type('continent',
    array(
        'capability_type'   => 'post',
        'edit_item'         => __('Edit Continent'),
        'has_archive'       => false,
        'labels'            => array(
            'add_new_item'  => __('Add new Continent'),
            'edit_item'     => __('Edit Continent'),
            'name'          => __('Continents'),
            'singular_name' => __('Continent')
        ),
        'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-location-alt',
        'public'            => true,
        'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'moving-to'),
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'supports'          => array('editor', 'thumbnail', 'title')
    )
);
```

Regular posts can reference this continent (using the [ACF Pro plugin](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/pro/)) and I am pulling these posts into the page using a second WP_Query loop. All working fine so far.

My problem is that I cannot get pagination to work. I would like to be able to use /moving-to/continent-name/page/2 to display more posts. I am checking for `get_query_var('paged')` but cannot seem to call the URL using /page/2 or ?paged=2.

Comment: I think the issue is down to the nesting of one content type in another. I have raised a new question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/254219/wordpress-rewrite-rule-for-nested-post-types

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up query for pagination, look at this example :

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
    'post__in' => $ids,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 15);

query_posts($args);
```

Comment: The query works fine (I can manually set the $paged variable), but I cannot get the URL /page/2 to work, so $paged is always 1.